# writing collection of collection to csv file using csv helper

Tags: c#, csv

I am using csvhelper to write data to a csv file. I am using C# and VS2010. The object I wish to write is a complex data type object of type `Dictionary< long,List<HistoricalProfile>>`

Below is the code I am using to write the data to the csv file:

```
Dictionary<long, List<HistoricalProfile>> profiles 
    = historicalDataGateway.GetAllProfiles(); 

var fileName = CSVFileName + ".csv";
CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(fileName));

foreach (var items in profiles.Values)    
{
    writer.WriteRecords(items);
}

writer.Dispose();
```

When it loops the second time I get an error

> The header record has already been written. You can't write it more than once.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here. My final goal is to have a single csv file with a huge list of records.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I would go more low-level and iterate through the collections myself:

```
var fileName = CSVFileName + ".csv";

var writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);



foreach (var items in profiles.Values)
{
    writer.WriteLine(/*header goes here, if needed*/);
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(item.property1 +"," +item.propery2...);
    }
}
writer.Close();
```

If you want to make the routine more useful, you could use reflection to get the list of properties you wish to write out and construct your record from there.

Comment: I know this is a reply from many years ago, but I think it is generally bad advice to tell someone to write CSV records him/herself, without a library. There are many complexities you forget in your example here, like commas inside your fields.

Comment: It's a CSV string. If you need a library to help you you're in the wrong profession.

Comment: @JuannStrauss: so will handle escaping newlines, quotes, or commas in the values?

Comment: It's an example. This isn't domyworkforme.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this library http://www.filehelpers.net/ this makes it very easy to read and write CSV files

Then your code would just be

```
var profiles = historicalDataGateway.GetAllProfiles();  // should return a list of HistoricalProfile
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<HistoricalProfile>();
// To Write Use:
engine.WriteFile("FileOut.txt", res);
```

Comment: I use this one all the time for very large csv files and custom classes

Comment: @Daveo - Forgive me, but your comment "should return a list of HistoricalProfile" implies that you're suggesting the OP must change their objects which may not be an option. His complex object already contains a list so he could use `engine.WriteFile("FileOut.csv", profiles(counter));` in a loop to write out each list. Also I'm not entirely familoar with the FileHelpers but doesn't it require your class (`HistoricalProfile` in this case) to be decorated thusly `[DelimitedRecord(",")]`?

Comment: Yes your correct, and the class does need to be decorated. But this is a very simple change

Comment: I cant change my objects as it is used by other api's. I finally use a lowlevel method provided by Juann Strauss and it worked like a charm. Thank guys for all your help.

Comment: @Pawan that's fine use Juann code. Just ensure if you have any commas in  your data that your escape them